# Rails migration will not run in prod

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, ruby-on-rails-5

I am transforming some data with a rails migration:

```
class MigrateInstancesToFacets < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    say "Found #{Instance.where(rev: nil).count} records to migrate"

    say_with_time "Migrating instances..." do
      user = User.first
      count = 0
      Instance.find_each do |instance|
        CatalogFacet.create(
          photo: instance.photo,
          catalog: instance.catalog,
          user: user
        )
        instance.update(rev: true)
        count += 1
      end
      count
    end
    fail_count = Instance.where(rev: nil).count
    fail "Found #{fail_count} not migrated records" unless fail_count == 0
  end
end
```

I first ran it in my development environment, and all was smooth.
Then I ran it in my production env, but this fails:

```
pi@pi0:~/pt_api $ RAILS_ENV="production" rake db:migrate
I, [2017-09-04T07:11:51.315838 #29058]  INFO -- : Migrating to MigrateInstancesToFacets (20170831110928)
== 20170831110928 MigrateInstancesToFacets: migrating =========================
-- Found 25671 records to migrate
-- Migrating instances...
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

uninitialized constant Instance::Catalog
/home/pi/pt_api/db/migrate/20170831110928_migrate_instances_to_facets.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in change'
/home/pi/pt_api/db/migrate/20170831110928_migrate_instances_to_facets.rb:8:in `block in change'
/home/pi/pt_api/db/migrate/20170831110928_migrate_instances_to_facets.rb:5:in `change'
NameError: uninitialized constant Instance::Catalog
/home/pi/pt_api/db/migrate/20170831110928_migrate_instances_to_facets.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in change'
/home/pi/pt_api/db/migrate/20170831110928_migrate_instances_to_facets.rb:8:in `block in change'
/home/pi/pt_api/db/migrate/20170831110928_migrate_instances_to_facets.rb:5:in `change'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

It is saying that it cannot access the catalog on the instance. I have opened op a console and run the same code there and it is all good.
Is it not loading the environment when migrating?

---EDIT---
Instance model:

```
class Instance < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :catalog
  belongs_to :photo
  before_destroy :delete_photo

  def delete_photo
    catalog = Catalog.find self.catalog_id
    catalog.delete_photo(self.photo_id)
  end

end
```

Comment: Tried using bundle exec rake db:migrate?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - but unfortunately that didn't change anything...

Comment: One major problem here is that you are running `.create` and never checking the return value to see if the record was saved or not.

Comment: Please, post the `Instance` model code.

Comment: @GokulM Added...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing the instance as it is can you try updating your migration code to create it with the `_id` column

```
CatalogFacet.create(
  ...
  catalog_id: instance.catalog_id, 
  ...
)
```

Comment: That does get me a bit further...Now the error comes ehn I try to update the instance further down

Comment: Can you post the log of that fail?

Comment: One thing in the `delete_photo` method you can go without the first line `catalog = Catalog.find self.catalog_id` the `belgons_to` association will make you automatically able to call catalog inside the model

Comment: Also if you want to keep that line better to call `::Catalog` so the instance doesn't get confused and try to search for a `Catalog` deceleration under the `Instance` class/module

Comment: the reason I'm doing the migration is to get rid of the Instance - but yeah you are right

Comment: the error is exactly the same, only it gets reported on `instance.update(rev: true)`this line instead

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153613/discussion-between-mark-jad-and-martin).